# Egyptian representations of $1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\ F(n)\ (\mbox{where}\ n\in\mathbb N:=\{1\ 2\ \ldots\})\ $ be the least cardinality $\ |A|\ $ of a set $\ A\subseteq\mathbb N  $ such that:

1. $\ \min A=n $
2. $\ \sum_{x\in A}\frac 1x = 1 $

**QUESTION**   Is set $\ \{n\in\mathbb N:\ \frac{F(n)}n\le 2\}\ $ finite?

> Background:

Roughly speaking, $\ \frac {F(n)}n\ \ge\ e-1,\ $ where $\ e:=exp(1)\ $ is one of the Euler's constants, $\ 2.718\ldots.\ $ This induces a bunch of natural questions, I have restricted myself to just one. Please, feel free to enjoy addressing also related questions.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you for fixing my typo (sloppy me).

Comment: Have you calculated a few values of $F(n)$ and then consulted the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I was hoping that some numerically literate people will provide an initial and relatively extensive table of F(n). Myself, I did something old fashion in a precomputer style like a reincarnation of a 17th century Basho's frog. You decide how promising is my (very fractional) answer below--I hope that it will get amplified in capable hands, and it can be followed by more numerical activities.

Comment: All you need is the first few terms, then you look it up at the OEIS. Exceptional levels of numerical literacy not required.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lots of questions along these lines were raised by Erdos and Graham and many have been solved by Croot, Greg Martin and others.  In particular, [Croot](https://eudml.org/doc/279607) has shown that any rational number $r$ can be represented as a 
sum of unit fractions with denominators lying in the interval $[N, (e^r+o(1))N]$ for all large $N$ (indeed his result is more precise, quantifying also the $o(1)$ term).   In particular your $F(N)$ is $\sim (e-1)N$ for all large $N$.  For related work, see also [Martin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811112.pdf).

Comment: Lucia, super! Do these authors mentioned by you illustrate their results on concrete numerical examples? (possibly, they are too advanced for this :) ) --- Myself, I'll make a certain connection with other equally ancient topics.